# How to replace the forward slash in a javascript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript

I am not a programmer, but know a little here and there. This is a bookmarklet I have in my browser. It is supposed to take the url of the page I am on, and when clicked, takes me to another site (example.com), and pass this first site into the url of the second site (e.g. sitechecker.com).

Problem is, the trailing slash on the example.com/ prevents sitechecker from working, so i need to get rid of the trailing slash somehow when its passed to the other site.

E.g.
No Good
http://www.example.com**/**

Good
http://www.example.com

Bookmarklet code:

```
javascript:(function(){ var url=location.href; var url=url.replace(/^(http|https):\/\//i,''); window.open('https://www.widgetfactory.com/index.html/all//'+encodeURIComponent(url)+'/Oc?l=us')})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following regex  `url.replace(/\/$/, "");` Exm. below

```
var url = 'http://www.example.com/';
console.log(url.replace(/\/$/, ""));
```

Comment: Seems to have fixed the trailing slash, but now the slashes after http:// are turning into html entities instead: 

http%253A%252F%252Fwww.example.com

Comment: This regex is working fine and is only removing the trailing slash. But in your code, you have encodeURIComponent  function which is encoding the URL. Remove the function if you do not need the encoding.